# Does having unused columns effect the indexing of the table

Tags: postgresql, database-design, index, table

I have a table where there are some columns which are empty and they are not used. That table has to be indexed multiple times based on the application. Does having these empty columns in my table slow down the indexing of the other columns or it does not have any effect?

Comment: When you say "slow down the indexing", do you mean slow down queries, the building of indexes themselves, or something else?

Comment: Just curious - why is an application indexing a table multiple times?

Comment: Are the unused columns present in any of the indexes?

Comment: @George.Palacios I meant to say slow down the queries.

Comment: @Vérace Not the table mostly specific records

Comment: @jjanes no, the columns are not part of indices

Comment: I think there might be a bit of confusion about terminology here. Tables with regular inserts and deletes become fragmented (read about its MVCC architecture where my understanding is that what Oracle calls REDO and UNDO are actually stored in the same table as ordinary records),hence the need to VACUUM. Indexes are the same and require REBUILDING. My understanding of what you were asking was that you were **changing** the index structure (different fields). I think that you should expand on "table has to be indexed multiple times based on the application". Ordinary activity is not problematic